# Create function from a Boolean field odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to create a function that checks whether the value of a boolean is True or False. If this boolean is True, I would like to execute a sequence of instructions. This function is created in the same class as my booleen field. Do I have to use a function decorator?

My class :

```
class ResPartner_school(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.partner.school'
    _order = 'id desc'

    half_pension = fields.Boolean(string='Restauration Scolaire', copy=False)
```

My Function :

```
def synchroHalfPension(self):
    if self.half_pension:
        print "BOOLEAN TRUE"
    else:
        print "BOOLEAN FALSE"
```

How to simply verify that my function works ?

I am a beginner.

Thank you

EDIT : The first part of my problem is solved and thank you. Now I notice something, the message is displayed as soon as I activate the boolean in Odoo. I would like the "half_pension is on" message to appear only when I save my form. How can I do that? cordially –

Comment: It's just a simple test for made a real function. 
It's just to be sure to go into the function when the booleen is True :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple, you can decorate your method with **api.onchange**,

```
@api.onchange('half_pension')
def synchroHalfPension(self):
    if self.half_pension:
        print "half_pension is on"
    else:
        print "half_pension is off"
```

above function will be called whenever the boolean will change.

hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, it works. I was rather left on the decorator @ api.depends but it did not work. And I do not see the difference between the two. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I notice something, the message is displayed as soon as I activate the boolean in Odoo. I would like the "half_pension is on" message to appear only when I save my form. How can I do that? cordially

Comment: You should edit your question and add these new information to it!